# Android Developers LinearLayout - I have a repeating list and want 1 button at the bottom of the screen, I keep getting one button per line

Tags: android, xml, layout, button, android-linearlayout

I am trying a task that should probably be simple..I want one button at the bottom across the bottom of the screen (floating preferably), while I have a scrollable list above that (I was able to do this in a tutorial with a simple listview and buitton).But, my  list is a LinearLayout that I fill with a SimpleCursorAdapter and a viewBinder. Since I am using this LinearLayout I keep getting One button per line item, instead of one at the bottom of the screen. I have tried wrapping it with a table layout, relative layout, using two LinearLayouts, etc. Every time I get one button per line. Is this because of the way I am getting the data with a cursor adapter and filling it into the listview? Do I need to use a "merge" in my xml file? Is there a way to make two xml files and then call them both? Do I need to switch to a ListView or another way of displaying the data? This is my first app that I am trying start to finish on my own, so some of this stuff trips me up. I will include my code for the LinearLayout, please note that this is just the list without my extra button added (i deleted all my failed attempts). So I would be looking to modify the code below to contain one button that floats at the bottom of the screen all the time.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
          android:layout_width="290dp"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnToClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:drawableLeft="@+drawable/android_button"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight=".1">
    </Button>

    <TextView android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvViewRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"> 
     </TextView>

     <TextView android:text="@+id/text11"
        android:id="@+id/text11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"> 
     </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
        android:layout_weight=".20"/> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text9"
        android:layout_column="5" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"  
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" 
        android:layout_weight=".1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text10" 
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
        android:layout_weight=".15"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text12" 
        android:layout_column="8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnToClick2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler3"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" 
        android:background="@+drawable/coup0a"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        >
     </Button>
```

Thanks in advance!
-Joe

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the button as a footer or a header according to your needs. You can try this code .The R.layout.header and footer are separate xml layout files which you would have to define.

```
View header =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,null);  
View footer =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer,null);   
addHeaderView(header); 
addFooterView(footer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely use a listview for this job. Listviews are highly optimized for displaying many entries. Just let your activity extend from a ListActivity and create a layout xml file with a listview widget that has the id "@android:id/list" and the listview activity will hook onto that list automatically. You are free to place other widgets in the layout aswell. Here is an example layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseOther"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_fav"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It has a list with a button sitting on the bottom of the screen at all times, even if you have a long list of items.